# Enviar e-mail função mail() usando UOL Host

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho a seguinte classe para envio de e-mails

```
  class EmailEnviarDao {

    public function __construct() {}

    public function enviaEmail($email)  {

      $cabecalhos  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $cabecalhos .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
      $cabecalhos .= 'To: '.$email->getNomeAlvo().' <'.$email->getEmailAlvo().'>' . "\r\n";
      $cabecalhos .= 'From: '.$email->getNomeRemete().' <'.$email->getEmailRemete().'>' . "\r\n";

       print "<pre>";
       //print_r($email)."<br><br><br><br>";
       print $email->getEmailAlvo()."<br>";
       print $email->getAssunto()."<br>";
       print $email->getMensagem()."<br>";
       print $cabecalhos;
       print "</pre>";  

      if(@mail($email->getEmailAlvo(), $email->getAssunto(), $email->getMensagem(), $cabecalhos)) {

         return array('success'=>'1','errors'=>'0K');

      } else {

          return array('success'=>'0','errors'=>"Não conseguimos enviar o e-mail");

      }    

    }   

  }
```

`$email`, é um `objeto` que já foi testado em `OK`.

os prints dentro da classe imprimem

```
contato@hotplateprensas.com.br
Re: Quero Comprar
Email enviado pelo site da Hotplate Prensas


Nome: Eu

Telefone: 3333333333

E-mail: jose@oi.com.br

Intersse: Quero Comprar

Descrição:
teste 1

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
To: Hotplate Prensas 
From: Eu
```

Uso a hospedagem do UOL Host e o e-mail não vai de jeito nenhum.

Alguma orientação?

Comment: troque `@mail` por `mail` e veja se alguma mensagem de erro aparece na página ou nos logs.

Comment: não retorna erro algum, só não envia, embora a resposta é de que enviou mas nem na caixa de span chega a mensagem

Comment: Consulte o manual e serviço de suporte do seu provedor de hospedagem. Cada provedor possui suas políticas de uso. Normalmente exigem envio de email autenticado e pode encontrar isso nos manuais do provedor.